# Building 4.5 code without the 4.5 runtime installed on the machine?

Tags: msbuild, build-automation, .net-4.5

We have a large & complex system running under .Net 4.0.  We want to start introducing code written for .Net 4.5, but can't (yet) assume that .Net 4.5 is installed on all the developer machines, build machines and test labs.  So I'm looking for a way to compile certain projects in MSBuild using  assemblies which are available on disk, on machines which have only .Net 4.0 installed.

Per the documentation it seems possible. The 4.5 reference assemblies are available in the msbuild environment, and I've been experimenting with the [TargetFrameworkVersion, FrameworkPathOverride and TargetFrameworkMoniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx) attributes, but so far without success.

Any hints, suggestions or working samples would be most helpful.

Comment: Why bother?  The .NET 4.0 reference assemblies will work fine.  If a machine has .NET 4.5 installed then the app will run with that version, it is not a side-by-side version like .NET 4 was.  Using .NET 4.5 reference assemblies on one machine and not another just produces broken builds.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. I'm looking for the MSBuild settings which will enable compiling code written for 4.5 on a machine which doesn't have 4.5 installed.

Comment: I don't get it, do you hope that 4.5 teleports to the machine to make the build succeed?  It is not just the reference assemblies, the compiler has fairly heavy changes to support async/await.  Not to mention the msbuild .targets files.

Comment: it's less about teleporting and more about whether it is possible to achieve a working build just by copying binaries (as many as needed included CSC, MSBUILD, etc) to the build machine vs actually installing the SDK.   (BTW thanks for your patience so far, I'll get it eventually...)

Comment: MSBuild of .NET 4 should be unable to handle the situation even if you present .NET 4.5 reference assemblies. You will have to install .NET 4.5 and it will update the MSBuild as well.

Answer (score 1):

To build a .NET Framework 4.5 application, you must also have the .NET Framework 4.5 reference assemblies.

**Installation**

The .NET Framework 4.5 replaces the common language runtime (CLR), targets, tasks, and tools of the .NET Framework 4 without renaming them. Essentially, it creates a modified and improved .NET Framework 4.